# Using fields defined in constructor - Python

Tags: python, sql, scope

I have a class as below that I'm using to connect to a remote SQL server instance from a linux server python web app. I define and set cursor in the **init** constructor and wish to use it throughout the class. How do I do this? I come form a java background and don't understand the scope and protection levels of Python fields.

```
import pyodbc

class SQLSeverConnection():


    def __init__(self, DSN, user, password, database):
        connectionString = 'DSN=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;DATABASE=%s;' % (DSN, user, password, database)
        connection = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)
        cursor = connection.cursor()

    def getColumnData(self, columnName, tableName):

        cursor.execute('SELECT ' columnName ' FROM ' tableName ' ORDER BY timestamp')
        data = cursor.fetchall()

        return data

    def getColumnTitles(self, tableName):
        cursor.execute('select column_name,* from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'tableName' order by ordinal_position')

        columns = cursor.fetchall()

        return columns

    def getTableNames(self):
        cursor.execute('SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = ''BASE TABLE''')

        tables = cursor.fetchall()

        return tables
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: Python's "methods" are really plain functions, and local variables are plain local variables. To set / access instance attributes, you **must** use the current instance, which is passed as first argument to the function (and by convention named `self`):

```
class SQLSeverConnection():


    def __init__(self, DSN, user, password, database):
        connectionString = 'DSN=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;DATABASE=%s;' % (DSN, user, password, database)
        self.connection = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)
        self.cursor = connection.cursor()

    def getColumnData(self, columnName, tableName):

        self.cursor.execute('SELECT ' columnName ' FROM ' tableName ' ORDER BY timestamp')
        data = self.cursor.fetchall()

        return data

    def getColumnTitles(self, tableName):
        self.cursor.execute('select column_name,* from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'tableName' order by ordinal_position')

        columns = self.cursor.fetchall()

        return columns

    def getTableNames(self):
        BASE_TABLE ='BASE_TABLE'
        self.cursor.execute('SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'')

        tables = self.cursor.fetchall()

        return tables
```

Now using a single shared cursor for all operations is brittle, you'd better instanciate a new cursor for each operation. Also, since a cursor is an iterable, you may want to return the cursor itself and let client code iterate over it, it might save some memory...

```
class SQLSeverConnection(object):

    def __init__(self, DSN, user, password, database):
        connectionString = 'DSN=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;DATABASE=%s;' % (DSN, user, password, database)
        self.connection = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)

   def getCursor(self):
       return self.connection.cursor()  

    def getColumnData(self, columnName, tableName):
        cursor = self.getCursor() 
        cursor.execute('SELECT ' columnName ' FROM ' tableName ' ORDER BY timestamp')
        return cursor

    # etc
```

Oh and yes: using `mixCased` is not pythonic, we prefer `all_lower` ;)

Comment: Thanks for the swift response, I'm still getting errors on the self.cursor.execute() statements - Expected:)

Comment: I don't think getters are very pythonic either

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: getters are unpythonic (because useless - we do have computed attributes) when all the do is returning a plain attribute. In the above case, `getCursor()` is not returning a plain attribute of the `SQLServerConnection` instance...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, can you not just create a `self.cursor =...` in the init method and call self.cursor where needed?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes you can but it means you have a single shared cursor for all operations on a given SQLServerConnection instance. If you try to execute another statement while iterating over the results of a previous SELECT statement you'll be in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

change cursor to self.cursor

```
def __init__(self, DSN, user, password, database):
    connectionString = 'DSN=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;DATABASE=%s;' % (DSN, user, password, database)
    connection = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)
    self.cursor = connection.cursor()

def getColumnData(self, columnName, tableName):

    self.cursor.execute('SELECT ' columnName ' FROM ' tableName ' ORDER BY timestamp')
    data = self.cursor.fetchall()

    return data
```